# Convert from Radians to Degrees Wrong

Tags: objective-c

I need to convert radians to degrees. I have tried this by x*180/Pi the problem is  my output angles are in degrees minutes seconds so the small error in conversion leads to big problems.

```
For example: (aCos(0)*180)/Pi = 90.00000250
```

In the base 10 universe it should by 90.00000000

Comment: How did you define `Pi` and what is `aCos`? - And note that floating point numbers in C/Objective-C are using base 2, not base 10.

Comment: It looks like a typical floating point error. Try using doubles instead of floats. Also Martin, floats don't really "use" a base until they are displayed to the user, in which case it's typically base 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I was using acosf(float) when I should have been using aces(double)

Comment: That's why I asked for the definition of `aCos` :-)

Answer (score 14):

Use the following macro in your code to convert radians to degrees:

```
#define RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(radians) ((radians) * (180.0 / M_PI))
```

Example:

```
NSLog(@"Output radians as degrees: %f", RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(0.785398));
```

via [this link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/graphics/radians-to-degrees-and-degrees-to-radians.html).

Comment: Isn't that exactly what he did?

Comment: yup, made no difference :-/

Comment: @JakeDahl, you said that the "output angles are in degrees minutes seconds". Do you mean the output angle of the conversion, and how is this an issue?

Comment: @JakeDahl: `(acos(0)*180)/M_PI` gives exactly `90.00000` on my computer, so what is `aCos` and `Pi` ?

Comment: Well, i convert the decimal to DMS after i convert the radians to degrees. The problem is (aCos(0)*180)/Pi returns 90.00000250447817506938, but any other calculator will return 90

Comment: Martin R, Yes it will but I'm assuming you are looking at the debug console. You most likely formatted that string with %g, I need 8 decimals and if you use %0.8f it says 90.00000250

Comment: @JakeDahl: 1) I tested this with "%.30f" format - 2) You still did not tell us what functions `aCos` and `Pi` you are using - 3) Single precision floating point numbers (`float`) in C use a **binary** representation, and have a precision of about 7-8 decimal digits.

Comment: i use "acos(double)" and M_PI

Comment: I thought double was more accurate than float

Comment: @JakeDahl: As I said, `(acos(0)*180)/M_PI` gives **exactly** `90` on my computer.

Comment: Wow, "(acos(0)*180)/M_PI" works, I found my problem. I was using "acosf(float)" that stupid f made me lose my accuracy.

Answer (score 3):

The right solution is to import `GLKit`
Then you can use the following 2 functions already implemented by GLKit :
`GLKMathDegreesToRadians()`
`GLKMathRadiansToDegrees()`

With `GLKit` the values returned by the functions are good !

Objective-C :

```
import <GLKit.h>

float angleInRadian = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(360.0);
// Return 6.2831854820
float angleInDegrees = GLKMathRadiansToDegrees(angleInRadian);
// Return 360.0000000000
```

Swift :

```
import GLKit

let angleInRadian: Float = GLKMathDegreesToRadians(360.0)
// Return 6.2831855
let angleInDegrees: Float = GLKMathRadiansToDegrees(angleInRadian)
// Return 360.0
```

Comment: The degreesToRadians macro doesn't work, should be: ```#define degreesToRadians(degrees) ((degrees)/180.0*M_PI)``` (mind the parentheses), 360° = 2 * PI radians = 2 * 3,14 radians and not 0.6366197724

Comment: @Cyril hum, the formula you give is exactly the same as in my post. The one that it doesn't work perfectly. And 360/(180*3,14) = 360/565,2 = ~ 0,6369. I don't understand what you're trying to explain but I think you're wrong... By the way the 2 methods in the GLK library are more easy to use and the result is perfect with them.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. You can also `#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>`
 and use `GLKMathDegreesToRadians()` or `GLKMathRadiansToDegrees()`.

```
-(CGFloat) degreesToRadians:(CGFloat) degrees {
    return degrees == 0.0 ? 0: degrees * M_PI / 180;
}

-(CGFloat) radiansToDegrees:(CGFloat) radians {
    return radians == 0.0 ? 0: radians * 180 / M_PI;
}
```